# Mixing .NET 5/6 Clarification

Tags: .net

If we have a .NET Standard / .NET 5 NuGet package should we also support .NET 6 to take the advantage of the new performance issues that .NET 6 resolves?

I've notice that by referencing a .NET 5 project from a .NET 6 project will use a .NET 5 compilation which I guess means that you don't have the advantages of .NET 6 when this runs on .NET 6 runtime?

If I add .NET 6 to the referenced project I get different compilation file.

So, I guess my question is, does the advantages of .NET 6 are included in the runtime or in the compiled .dll or both?